# Constructing Lists

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python and I came across the following query. Can anyone explain why the following:

```
[ n**2 for n in range(1, 6)]
```

gives:

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: Here is some helpful reading: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

It is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). What is happening is similar to the following:

```
results = []
for n in range(1,6):
    results.append(n**2)
```

It therefore iterates through a list containing the values `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and squares each value. The result of the squaring is then added to the `results` list, and you get back the result you see (which is equivalent to `0**2, 1**2, 2**2`, etc., where the `**2` means 'raised to the second power').

This structure (populating a list with values based on some other criteria) is a common one in Python, so the list comprehension provides a shorthand syntax for allowing you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it down into manageable chunks in the interpreter:

```
>>> range(1, 6)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

```
>>> 2 ** 2   # `x ** 2` means `x * x`
4
>>> 3 ** 2
9
```

```
>>> for n in range(1, 6):
...   print n
1
2
3
4
5
>>> for n in range(1, 6):
...    print n ** 2
1
4
9
16
25
```

```
>>> [n ** 2 for n in range(1, 6)]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

So that's a [list comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).

If you break it down into 3 parts; separated by the words: 'for' and 'in' ..

eg.

[ 1  for  2  in  3 ]

Probably reading it backwards is easiest:

- 3 - This is the list of input into the whole operation
- 2 - This is the single item from the big list
- 1 - This is the operation to do on that item

part 1 and 2 are run multiple times, once for each item in the list that part 3 gives us. The output of part 1 being run over and over, is the output of the whole operation.

---

So in your example:

- 3 - Generates a list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -- [Range](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=range#range) runs from the first param to **one before** the second param
- 2 - 'n' represents a single number in that list
- 1 - Generates a new list of n**2 (n to the power of 2)

---

So an equivalent code would be:

```
result = []
for n in range(1, 6):
   result.append(n**2)
```

---

Finally breaking it all out:

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
output = []

v = input[0] # value is 1
o = v**2     # 1 to the power of two is 1
output.append(o)

v = input[1] # value is 2
o = v**2     # 2 to the power of two = (2*2) = 4
output.append(o)

v = input[2] # value is 3
o = v**2     # 3 to the power of two is = (3*3) = 9
output.append(o)

v = input[3] # value is 4
o = v**2     # 4 to the power of two is = (4*4) = 16
output.append(o)

v = input[4] # value is 5
o = v**2     # 5 to the power of two is = (5*5) = 25
output.append(o)
```

---